# Using Npgsql with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2008, npgsql

I need to work on a VSTO for Outlook 2007, hence I'm using VS2008 with .Net 3.5.1.
The add-in will read from a PostgreSQL database, so I'm going to use Npgsql.
When I compile o run the debug, I get this error:

> Problem generating manifest: This assembly is built by a runtime newer
>   than the current loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8013101B)

*Edit*
On VS2008SP1 on Windows2008R2x64, I tried Npgsql 2.2.4.3 from Github both for .Net 2.0 and .Net 3.5.1, changing the project' target framework accordingly, but the problem remains.
Any suggestion please? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify which Npgsql version you're using and exactly where you got it from (nuget, direct download...)

Comment: Thank you Shay, I am updating the OP